# DeprecationWarning when starting Vim with Powerline enabled since Python upgrade from 3.6.5 to 3.7.0

Tags: vim, powerline, vim-powerline

I was happily using [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) for Vim for a while now until today Homebrew installed a Python upgrade from 3.6.5 to 3.7.0. Since then, Powerline stopped working properly in Vim.

First, when starting Vim, there was an error saying that the `powerline` module could not be found, which makes sense, I guess, if `pip` installs packages per Python minor version.

So I installed the `powerline-status` package again using `pip` as [described in the docs](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#pip-installation):

```
pip install powerline-status
```

Now, the `ModuleNotFoundError` is gone and I get a working powerline in Vim, **but** every time I start Vim I get another error saying:

```
/must>not&exist/foo:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And I have to press Enter or any other key to continue, which is annoying.

If I remove the following commands for loading Powerline (as [described in the docs](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/other.html#vim-statusline)) from my `.vimrc`, the `DeprecationWarning` is gone, but obviously the Powerline is also gone then...

```
python3 from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python3 powerline_setup()
python3 del powerline_setup
```

I [searched their GitHub issues](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+imp+module+is+deprecated), but couldn't find anything related.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: There is an issue now: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1925. The resolution is: this is a problem in vim, not Powerline. vim is not yet ready for Python 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, the imp modules is deprecated.
As a workaround, change the commands you put into your .vimrc into the following:

```
silent! python3 from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python3 powerline_setup()
python3 del powerline_setup
```

the *silent!* keyword will suppress the error message.

[Source](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1925#issuecomment-402635097)